# How to pass a value to a search query

Tags: python, django

I am working with two pages and I would like to click on `a tag` on one page, which would insert a value to a search query on another page.

So here's my views.py:

```
def bikes_all(request):
  item_list = Bike.objects.all()

  category_q = request.GET.get('cat')

  if category_q:
      item_list = item_list.filter(category__pk=category_q)

  paginator = Paginator(item_list, 10)

  page = request.GET.get('page')

  try:
      items = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      items = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  context = {
    'items': items,
  }

  return render(request, "bikes_all.html", context)
```

and my template:

```
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'core:bikes_all' %}">
            <div class="form-row ">
            <div class="form-group col-5">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select id="cat" class="form-control" name="cat">
                    <option value="" {% if not request.GET.cat %} selected {% endif %}>Choose...</option>
                    {% for cat in category_list %}
                    <option value="{{ cat.pk }}" {% if request.GET.cat == cat.pk|slugify %} selected {% endif %}>
                        {{ cat }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and here's the `a tag` from another page:

```
            <div class="col-md-4 overlay zoom">
            <a href="{% url 'core:bikes_all'  %}">
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <img src="{% static '/img/category_choice/bike33.png' %}" class="img-fluid">
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                        <h2 class="card-title"
                            style="text-align: center; color: aliceblue; position: absolute; bottom:5px;">
                            Road Bikes
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

So I have `{% url 'core:bikes_all'  %}` in my href, which takes to `bikes_all.html` , but I would like to pass a search query within that href as well. I was trying to do `{% url 'core:bikes_all' request.GET.cat=2  %}` or `{% url 'core:bikes_all' category_q=2  %}`, but it didnt work.

The search query looks like that, when I filter the results by category `http://localhost:8000/bikes/all?cat=1`
So my aim is to redirect user to `http://localhost:8000/bikes/all?cat=2` , when he clicks on that `a tag` on first page.

Comment: `href="{% url 'core:bikes_all' %}?cat=2">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting GET parameters in your request so you need to pass that GET parameter in your url like this:

```
https://url?parameter=2
```

so set the `cat=i` in your `bikes_all` url:

```
{% url 'core:bikes_all' %}?cat=i
```